# Does Java foreach create copies?

Tags: java, foreach, jvm

I have a question about this foreach:

```
    for(Element e : nullProof(setOfElements)){
            // do stuff
    }
```

Let's assume I defined the function, nullProof, to return a non-null Set (because I heard you shouldn't pass null into an enhanced for-loop.  Is this true?):

```
    private Set<Element> nullProof(Set<Element> s){
          return s == null ? Collections.<Element> emptySet() : s;
    }
```

My question is...is it safe to call the **nullProof** function within the foreach?  Specifically, is the following header equivalent to:

```
    for(Element e : setOfElements){    //assuming setOfElements != null
```

I was wondering if someone could point me to some Java standard that says this is defined behavior.

Furthermore, can someone explain what actually happens "behind the scenes" when this foreach is called?

Let's say **setOfElements** has size 6.  For each iteration through **setOfElements**, does the JVM look up **setOfElements** 6 different times, or does it create a copy of that set and refer to the copy?  I'm trying to understand the behavior.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work

Comment: What do you mean by "look up?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly safe.

```
for(Element e :  nullProof(setOfElements)) {
```

is equivalent to

```
Set<Element> s = nullProof(setOfElements);
for(Element e :  s) {
```

As stated in the [JLS-14](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), *behind the scene* the for each loop is equivalent to:

```
for(Iterator<Element> it = s.iterator() ; it.hasNext() ; ) {
    Element e = it.next();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, and thanks for the JLS-14 link.  I'll give it a read, thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's safe because the actual collection must be resolved before any iteration takes place, but it masks your intention somewhat. In my opinion this is clearer:

```
if (setOfElements != null) {
    for (Element e : setOfElements) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or, you might want to reevaluate *why* you allow `setOfElements` to be `null` at all. Does it make sense to have it be an empty list in the first place, as opposed to `null`?

---

> Let's say `setOfElements` has size 6. For each iteration through `setOfElements`, does the JVM look up `setOfElements` 6 different times, or does it create a copy of that set and refer to the copy? I'm trying to understand the behavior.

No copying is involved. The enhanced `for`-loop uses an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) (as returned by the [`iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator()) method of any collection) to do its iteration. An `Iterator` is an object that is able to give you the elements of some collection one by one through its [`next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next()) method.